# encerrar etiquetas dentro de un div con js / table

Tags: javascript

compañeros me encuentro en un dilema
tengo el siguiente codigo, el cual elabora una tabla

```
let row = document.createElement("tr");

for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("td");
```

y dentro de un "td" elabora 2 etiquetas, img y span.

```
 else if (j === 1) {
     
        let bandera = document.createElement("img");
        bandera.setAttribute("class", "flag");
        bandera.setAttribute(
            "src",
            `images/banderas/circu/${DATOS[i].Abreviate}.png`
        );

        let localeLine = document.createElement("span");
        localeLine.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${DATOS[i].Locale}`));
        
        cell.appendChild(localeLine);
        cell.appendChild(bandera);
        
    }
```

me gustaria encerrar a las etiquetas < img > y < span > dentro de un div, con su respectiva clase.
espero puedan ayudarme
saludos

Comment: Siguiendo la misma lógica de lo que has hecho hasta ahora... ¿no se te ocurre como hacerlo?  Es decir, tan solo debes crear un elemento div, ponerle el atributo class, hacer los appendchild sobre el en lugar de cell, y luego en cell le haces un appendchild del div con todo lo anterior ya metido

Comment: en realidad si trate de hacer eso, pero no me funciona

Answer (score 1):

Creación del div:

```
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.setAttribute("class","tuClase");
```

Hacer que la imagen y el span sean sus hijos:

```
newDiv.appendChild(bandera);
newDiv.appendChild(localeline);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (j === 1) {
        let bandera = document.createElement("img");
        bandera.setAttribute("class", "flag");
        bandera.setAttribute(
            "src",
            `images/banderas/circu/${DATOS[i].Abreviate}.png`
        );

        let localeLine = document.createElement("span");
        localeLine.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${DATOS[i].Locale}`));
        
        let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.setAttribute("class","tuClase");

        cell.appendChild(newDiv);
        newDiv.appendChild(bandera);
        newDiv.appendChild(localeLine);
        
    }
```

Gracias, al final este fue lo que me funciono, pero me crea un div dentro del TD.

gracias por tu tiempo. saludos

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con esto?  ***pero me crea un div dentro del TD*** ... ¿donde querias crearlo pues?  Dentro de los TD se puede poner todo lo que quieras, en cambio, en un div no puedes poner un `TD` solo, sino dentro de una estructura de `<table>`  (bueno, si puedes, pero rompes la estructura de HTML y puede dar resultados impredecibles según el navegador como lo interprete)